# Diagramming and use of please as interjection

Tags: parts-of-speech, interjections, diagramming

When diagramming the sentence, "Simon, would you please sing now?", should I diagram Simon or you as the subject? Would you be diagrammed as pronoun and please as an interjection? I am trying to help my son diagram real-life sentences and am getting stuck myself.

Answer (score 1):

Simon is a vocative, which could be suppressed.

The rest is an infinitive proposition, with "you" as the subject.

Comment: @Melissa: additionally: I'm not into diagramming sentences, but 'please' here is a pragmatic marker (a politeness marker, along with 'kindly' when used in a similar way). Pragmatic markers are 'taken to be separate and distinct from the propositional content of the sentence' (see PRAGMATIC MARKERS: Bruce Fraser). Although not always 'added words or phrases etc', where they _are_ added words etc (eg _please_ here),  pragmatic markers are probably best considered to be outside the matrix structure of a sentence in the same way as parentheticals.

Comment: The sentence without the vocative is a yes/no question with _you_ as the subject. _Please_ is an adverb -- it happens to be a pragmatic particle, but it patterns as an adverb syntactically -- and _sing_ is indeed an infinitive, but it's the infinitive form that's required after the modal auxiliary _would_ that is inverted with the subject _you_.

Comment: You have to select the patterns you need to bolster this model. *'Would you very please sing./?' // *'Would you sing(,) very please./?' *'There she sat, singing please.' I'll be glad to see a move back towards accepting a reasonable contribution of semantic (and the inclusion of pragmatic) requirements for word-class determination.